# Import project into Eclipse but NOT into workspace folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project in /a/b that I import into Eclipse but it creates a copy in /a/workspace and those are the java files I'm editing in Eclipse. I want Eclipse to be editing the files in /a/b so that I can build manually from /a/b based on other dependencies. Is there a preference I can set or a different method of importing that makes this possible?

Comment: I remember when I used Eclipse that when importing it asks you if you want to copy it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you select `Import -> Existing Project into Workspace`, if you do not select `Copy projects into workspace`, it will just reference the project in its current location.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see this option because I kept trying File -> Import -> File System.